# How do I get rid of broken, invisible files that take up lots of space?

Tags: internal-storage

I tried downloading a pretty big mp4 file, but that failed because i didn't have enough space.

However, it filled up all my leftover storage. I tried getting rid of it but it doesn't show up in the file explorer. I checked hidden files.

Checking device care -> storage, it seems like it's in the "other" category.

I'm kinda desperate because i need the storage space to work. How do i clear it up?

Samsung galaxy Tab S4, Amdroid 10

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all the necessary files from your internal storage to somewhere else and do a factory reset. Then copy the files back. Should work.

Comment: In my opinion this is not a good idea as it will delete all app data stored in the app-private section. Therefore performing a factory reset should be the very last option.

Comment: I agree with robert, it's not a good idea if avoidable. However, i'm glad to have the option if i genuinely can't fix the problem in any other way